# How to save associations with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a student model that inherits from a user model using STI.  The user model `has_one profile`.  When creating a new student from a form, the create action of the students controller sucessfully produces an instance of the student model and also an instance of the students profile, which can be inspected by `@student.profile`.  At this stage,  the student.id, the profile.id, and the profile.user_id are nil. Under rails 4, I could just do @student.save, and both the student and the associated model would be saved. However, under rails 5, @student.save returns false, with an error message

```
:"profile.user"=>["can't be blank"]
```

How do I save @student instance with its associations in rails 5?

The relevant code is

```
  def create
    @student = build_student(params[:student])
    if @student.save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default=false
```

and in the profile model, I had set

```
validates :user, presence: true
```

which is old school, so it is clear why it did not work with `rails 5`. I tried in profile.rb

```
belongs_to user, required: true
```

but this did not work, giving a error

```
"profile.user"=>["must exist"]
```

In the end, I just set

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default=true
```

and used `optional: true` for my models which can be saved without belonging to a user.